# Increasing sequence of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Could anyone give me an example of an increasing sequence of random variable that converges in probability to a random variable but their expectation does not? Thanks

I tried to formulate this example, but not sure it is increasing sequence.

$$X_n = \begin{cases}
n^2 \quad \ \ \text{if}\ \ 0\le \omega\le \frac{1}{n}\\
0 \quad \quad\text{if}\ \ \frac{1}{n}< \omega \le 1
\end{cases}$$

Thanks.

Comment: It is not an increasing sequence since for 0.5, $X_3(0.5) = 0 \not= 4 =  X_2(0.5)$. You can construct such examples for any n, arbitrarily large. $X_{n+1}(1/n)=0\neq n^2=X_n(1/n)$

Comment: I do not understand your solution. Could you be more clear.

Comment: I was just commenting that yours is not an increasing sequence. If it were, $X_{n+1}(\omega)\geq X_n(\omega) \forall n, \omega$ and I gave you an example where that doesn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments above your sequence is not increasing.

If $X_n$ increases to $X$ and all these random variables have finite expectation then $EX_n \to EX$. This follows by an application of Montone Convergence Theorem to the sequence $(X_n-X_1)$.

[Your sequence cannot be increasing because of this result].

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy, don't we need $X_n\ge 0$ for all $n$?

Comment: @MissQ  $X_n-X_1 \geq 0$. That is why I am applying the theorem to this sequence instead of $(X_n)$ itself.

Comment: @MissQ You get $E(X_n-X_1) \to E(X-X_1)$. You can add $EX_1$ to both sides to get $EX_n \to EX$.